# how to manage layers in position:absolute css block

Tags: jquery, html, css, position

How can i show reveal div always on top of others btn div ..which is positioned absolute on map element, and have to stay where it is.

Other words how to make green 1111111111 on top of red 232323232

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QWE6x/33/)

```
<div class="map">
    <div class="btn" style="top:20px; left:40px;">
        1212121
        <div class="reveal">1111111111</div>
    </div>
        <div></div>
    <div class="btn" style="top:130px; left:100px;">
        232323232
        <div class="reveal">222222222</div>
    </div>
</div>


.map{
    background-color: yellow; 
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
}

.btn{
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
}

.reveal {
    background-color: green;
    height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    display: none;
    position:relative;
    z-index:4;
}
```

Comment: You have to give the first btn div a higher z-index than the second btn.

Comment: but I have about 50 on map ..and don't know which should be on top which. btn divs do not overaps

Comment: Ya, something like that, e.g, using only CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/QWE6x/34/

Comment: Thank You very much :) ..changing z-index on hover ..nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition:

`The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.`

`An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.`

To get 1212121 to be on top of 232323232 you will have to give .btn on hover a higher z-index

Comment: 1212121 and 232323232 do not overlap in this example. Problem was with reveal 1111111111 showed on hover (it was under 232323232) ..so anyway yes ..i had to change z-index on hover like @A. Wolff suggested